# How to crop this triangle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have this image.I want to crop just triangle not its white background for logo im creating.How can i do it in illustrator or photoshop?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both programs can be used. I recommend Illustrator because you will get a vector image which can be resized freely without any loss of sharpness.

What to do? Answer=Trace it manually in Illustrator

- copy your image to Illustrator
- draw one element over the image.

Automatic tracing is inaccurate due the image noise and sharp corners.

The elements are seemingly identical and after drawing one, the others can be made by copying, rotating 60 degrees and flipping. Place them manually over the image. Of course you could draw them, too, but they easily would not be identical enough. Your image is too coarse.

Drawing: Use the line tool, remember to join the line segments to one path. Beware the snapping. Goto View menu and turn at least snapping to grid off.

[image]

Your original design has no stroke, but black fill. Take them.

Remove the original and group your shapes to keep them together. Ready.

The result:

[image]

**Addendum due the comment**: Here's a step-by-step quide. The pen is used instead of the line tool. The joining is unnecessary. The rotations are minimized. Formerly I used rotate + flip, but actually rotation is enough in this case.

[image]

Comment: can you tell me step by step

Comment: @its_sanket the receipe is ready.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing this in Photoshop then

Step 1: Remove the background color either by magic wand tool or go to select -color range - select the background color.

Step 2: Once the background color is selected, press the delete button. This will remove the background color.

Step 3: Go to file- save for web and devices - **SELECT PNG** and then save it.
(If you select Jpg, it will give you a white background)

[image]